# Writing revisions for all audit tables

Tags: hibernate-envers

I use Envers 3.5 with Spring.
Lets say I have a entity A with a relation to Entity B which has a relation to Entity C.
All Entities are audited. When I change something in entity C I can see the change in that audit table. What I want is to see the change in the audittable of entity A, too. It would be ok to see that change in entity B´s table.

Can this be done with envers?

(I´m sorry for my poor English knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question about Envers, however that is not possible currently.

First of all Envers doesn't have a way to automatically know what are the roots of entity trees, that is which entities should be marked as modified upon a child-entity modification.

Secondly it would cause a lot more data to be written on each change. It would be possible to implement using some custom annotations and "marker" revisions, but I guess that task waits for a contributor :)